# I am having trouble reading from standard input and/or command line

Tags: java

So I have been stuck on this forever. I need my code to accept multiple files in through the command line and read through the lines for specific info in the strings. If there are no files in the command line it must read through the standard in through a Scanner. Here is where I'm at.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class P1 {

static String readLine;
static int lineCount;
static int httpCount;
static int httpsCount;
static int ftpCount;
static int otherSchemesCount;
static int eduCount;
static int orgCount;
static int comCount;
static int otherDomainsCount;
static String protocol;
String schemeString;
static String testedLine;

P1() {

    lineCount = 0;
    httpCount = 0;
    httpsCount = 0;
    ftpCount = 0;
    otherSchemesCount = 0;
    eduCount = 0;
    orgCount = 0;
    comCount = 0;
    otherDomainsCount = 0;
}



boolean testLine(String testedLine) {
    if (testedLine.equals("end")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        lineCount++;
        String[] schemePart = readLine.split(":");
        String part1 = schemePart[0];

        if (part1.equals("http")) {
            httpCount++;

        } else if (part1.equals("https")) {
            httpsCount++;

        } else if (part1.equals("ftp")) {
            ftpCount++;

        } else {
            otherSchemesCount++;

        }

        if (readLine.contains("edu")) {
            eduCount++;
        } else if (readLine.contains("org")) {
            orgCount++;
        } else if (readLine.contains("com")) {
            comCount++;
        } else {
            otherDomainsCount++;
        }

    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    int i = 0;

    File testFile = new File(args[i]);

    if (args[0] == null) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        readLine = scan.nextLine();
    } else {      
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(testFile);
        readLine = scanFile.nextLine();
    }

    P1 countLines = new P1();

    boolean isEnded = false;
    System.out.println("Enter a line of text. "
            + "\nType 'end' to stop and count previous lines.");
    while (!isEnded) {
        //String testLine = countLines.getLine();
        isEnded = countLines.testLine(testedLine);
    }
    if (lineCount == 1) {
        System.out.println(">> Got " + lineCount + " line");
    } else {
        System.out.println(">> Got " + lineCount + " lines");
    }
    if (httpCount == 1) {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + httpCount + " instance of http");
    } else {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + httpCount + " instances of http");
    }
    if (httpsCount == 1) {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + httpsCount + " instance of https");
    } else {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + httpsCount + " instances of https");
    }
    if (ftpCount == 1) {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + ftpCount + " instance of ftp");
    } else {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + ftpCount + " instances of ftp");
    }
    if (otherSchemesCount == 1) {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + otherSchemesCount + " instance of other schemes");
    } else {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + otherSchemesCount + " instances of other schemes");
    }
    if (eduCount == 1) {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + eduCount + " instance of edu");
    } else {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + eduCount + " instances of edu");
    }
    if (orgCount == 1) {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + orgCount + " instance of org");
    } else {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + orgCount + " instances of org");
    }
    if (comCount == 1) {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + comCount + " instance of com");
    } else {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + comCount + " instances of com");
    }
    if (otherDomainsCount == 1) {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + otherDomainsCount + " instance of other domains");
    } else {
        System.out.println(">> Found " + otherDomainsCount + " instances of other domains   ");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're aware that you are only reading one line, right?

Comment: So, what is your question? Be more specific, and provide an sscce. You posted way too much code, I won't read it.

Comment: You would need, I think, to at least add a `readOneFile(Scanner &file)` and a `printResults()` function to simplify your program and make it easier to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a single Scanner:

```
Scanner scan = null;
if (args[0] == null) {
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
} else {      
    scan = new Scanner(testFile);
}
```

Then in the while loop:

```
while (!isEnded) {
    readLine = countLines.getLine();
    if(readLine == null)
        break;
    isEnded = countLines.testLine(readLine);
}
```

Comment: Jon Lin I appreciate such a quick response. I am ending up with a nullpointerexception. Here is one of the errors when I submit it into our grading system. 
Testing with input file named 10urls.lis (5% of points)
        Program failed when listing file(s) on command line 
         Enter a line of text. 
         Type 'end' to stop and count previous lines. 
         Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
         at P1.testLine(P1.java:37) 
         at P1.main(P1.java:91) 
        Output did not match; no points for this test

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: @Geoff Then check if it's null and stop the loop. I'm only pointing you in the right direction, I'm not going to do your work for you

Comment: I appreciate that. I don't want anyone to do my work for me. I just got to the point where I need a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

well if you want to read from a file the most common way is the following:

```
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));
```

I would suggest first of all not to use so many static variables. Try first to design your code and make a pseudocode to find how the code should look like without many details. For instance:

```
String arg=args[0];
if(arg==null) //read from system.in{
Scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
String line=sc.nextLine()
while(line!=null && line.size()>2){
    updateCounters(line); 
    line=sc.nextLine()
}\\end while

}
else
{ 
  BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));
  String line=reader.readline();
  //the rest are same as above
}
```

Comment: I somehow ended up with so many static variables because I kept continually getting this error. "non-static variable lineCount cannot be referenced from a static context". Not sure why. Any ideas? I've never run into that issue before. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Geoff that's because you're doing everything in the `main()` method, which is static, and you can call access instance variables from a static method. You'd be able to access them from a method that isn't static.